# Criar um arquivo em outro diretório

Tags: c, arquivo

Tenho uma pasta que contém meu arquivo .c, seu executável e outra pasta chamada `Arquivos`. Preciso que quando a função abaixo seja executada o arquivo seja criado na pasta `Arquivos` e não na pasta em que o .c e o .exe se encontram.

```
char nomeDoArquivo[100] = {'\0'};

printf("\nDigite o nome do arquivo: ");
scanf("%s", nomeDoArquivo);
fp = fopen(("Arquivos//%s", nomeDoArquivo),"w");
```

Comment: Veja se este codigo que achei na internet pode lhe ajudar:
[Criar diretorio Linux](https://www.vivaolinux.com.br/dica/Como-criar-um-diretorio-em-CC)

Answer (score 1):

A função `fopen` tem de receber a string com o caminho, e você está a passar `("Arquivos//%s", nomeDoArquivo)`, que não é valido. Para alem disso `/` não é uma caratere que precise de escapar e por isso não precisa de duas `//`.

A construção do caminho com pasta tem de ser feita previamente, e pode faze-lo à custa de [`sprintf`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/sprintf/):

```
char nomeFinal[200];
sprintf(nomeFinal, "Arquivos/%s", nomeDoArquivo);
```

A partir daí é só abrir com o caminho gerado:

```
FILE *fp = fopen(nomeFinal, "w");
```

Ressalvo que para funcionar assim como está a pasta `Arquivos` tem de existir.
Como nota, se a primeira coisa que faz com `nomeDoArquivo` é ler através de `scanf`, também não precisa de inicializar com `'\0'`, pois o `scanf` irá colocar o terminador.

Código completo para referência:

```
char nomeDoArquivo[100], nomeFinal[200];
printf("\nDigite o nome do arquivo: ");
scanf("%s", nomeDoArquivo);
sprintf(nomeFinal, "Arquivos/%s", nomeDoArquivo);
FILE *fp = fopen(nomeFinal,"w");
```